# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined not working in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome, dom

Am new to XML / HTML Nodes and am working on the code, which works well in IE but doesn't in other browsers. 
Below is the piece of code, which worries:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","SMoutput.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

//xmlDoc.async="false";
//xmlDoc.load("./SMoutput.xml");

var Server=xmlDoc.documentElement;
var fts = Server.childNodes[1];
var rows = Server.childNodes.length;
var cols = fts.childNodes.length;

var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
//var tabl = document.createElement("table");
var tabl = document.getElementById("ftsinfo");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var length=0;
    fts = Server.childNodes[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        var cell = document.createElement("td");


        ***var define=fts.childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var cellText = document.createTextNode(define);***


        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        row.appendChild(cell);

        length= length+cell.innerText.length;
        //cell.innerText= length

        if ( length > max)
        {
            max=length;
        }


        if(cell.innerText=="Up")
        {
            cell.innerText=""
            //cell.innerText= max
            cell.style.backgroundImage="url('up.png')";

        }

        if(cell.innerText=="Down")
        {
            cell.innerText=""
            //cell.innerText= max
            cell.style.backgroundImage="url('down.png')";


        }


        row.style.fontSize= "14";
        row.style.color= "black";
    }

tblBody.appendChild(row);
tabl.appendChild(tblBody);
tabl.setAttribute("border", "1");
```

This is a function which is called during Body onload in below :

```
<BODY onload="PingServer();showResult();DoInit();" onrefresh="PingServer();">

    <div id="contents">
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana;color:brown" align="center">Mining Services Monitor</h4>

        <table id="ftsinfo" align="center">
                <tr bgcolor='lightgray' style="font-family:verdana;color:Brown;font-size:12px">
                    <td>Service</td><td>Host</td><td>Port</td><td>Status</td>
                </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

on further troubleshooting, I found this piece of code is causing the problem:

```
var define=fts.childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var cellText = document.createTextNode(define);
```

When I open the link, chrome does not load the data and says "`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"

, when it goes through the firstline var define=fts.childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue

All I want is to get the text value from the childnodes to be passed into celltext variable to be displayed.

This is working in IE but not in other browsers, am also new to these. Finding it tough to crack. Please help.

The below is the sample of SMoutput.xml :

```
<network>
 <server>
<name>PROD JBOSS Service</name>
<host>Hostname1</host>
<port>Portnumber1</port>
<result>Up</result>
</server>
<server>
<name>PROD Database</name>
<host>Hostname2</host>
<port>Portnumber2</port>
<result>Down</result>
</server>
```

Comment: Please post a minimal sample of the XML that causes that error.

Comment: var define=fts.childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var cellText = document.createTextNode(define); is the piece of code causing problems..

Comment: am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined"

Comment: We need to see a minimal sample of `SMoutput.xml` that causes that error.

Comment: Sorry,  I misunderstood... Below is the sample of SMoutput.xml :

Comment: <network>
  <server>
       <name>PROD JBOSS Service</name>
       <host>Hostname</host>
        <port>123</port>
        <result>Up</result>
  </server>
  <server>
        <name>PROD Database</name>
        <host>Hostname2</host>
       <port>1234</port>
       <result>Down</result>
  </server>
  </network>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the sample in the question, properly marked up as code so that we can easily read it and see any white space between nodes.

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to work with the `childNodes` collection as depending on white space text nodes between element nodes and whether the DOM implementation includes them into the tree you can get different results with different implementations. Instead, once you have `xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;`, you can use `getElementsByTagName` e.g.

```
var serverElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("server");
for (var i = 0, l = serverElements.length; i < l; i++) {
  var server = serverElements[i];
  var nameEl = server.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];
  var hostEl = server.getElementsByTagName("host")[0];
  var portEl = server.getElementsByTagName("port")[0];
  var resultEl = server.getElementsByTagName("result")[0];
  // now here you can extract the data, for older versions of IE you need to access the `.text` property, for other browsers and recent version the `.textContent` property e.g.
  var name = nameEl.textContent ? nameEl.textContent : nameEl.text;
  var host = hostEl.textContent ? hostEl.textContent : hostEl.text;
  // here you can add the `name`, `host` etc. to your HTML table
}
```